# Тире вместо запятой

Tags: пунктуация

Возможно ли здесь вместо запятой тире поставить?

`Я всё сделал правильно, и поэтому я получил суперредкий приз.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Я всё сделал правильно, **и поэтому** я получил суперредкий приз.*

Это сложносочиненное предложение (ССП), запятая является основным знаком. Тире ставится **[в особых случаях](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=135#pp135),** должна быть соответствующая семантика и структура предложения, при которой можно подчеркнуть паузу.

Поэтому для этого сообщения нужно подобрать **другую** синтаксическую конструкцию и добавить нужный  **смысловой оттенок**.

Например, так: *Что ж здесь удивительного? *Вот я **сдЕлал все правильно — и получИл** суперредкий приз.**

Здесь между однородными членами ставится тире при наличии оттенка противопоставления  **[(Розенталь, пункт 3).](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=100#pp100)** Структура предложения позволяет сделать увеличенную паузу.